# IDE that runs ON ios

Tags: c++, ios, c, ide

Has anyone found and IDE for programming ON iOS? Specifically I'm coding for the nds in c++, but I was wondering if there really is any IDE that is for coding on iOS. If anyone's heard of one, please tell me the name because I have not been able to find one.

Comment: You need an IDE that actually runs on the device (iPhone / iPad)?

Comment: Yes, while I was looking for one so I could code away from my house since I dont actually have a laptop xD.

Comment: Then codea is the only full blown IDE that would come to my mind....

Comment: @Till Also, for writing C/C++/Objective-C, there's an ondevice toolchain, it's not an IDE though (command-line tools only, but it's already more than enough).

Comment: Try CppCode app (http://cppcode.info). It supports code-complete and another great features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not specifically an IDE for C++, but there are alternatives:

- [Codea](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/) is an application for iPad that lets you write Lua code on your device;
- You can install the [LLVM-Clang toolchain](http://ininjas.com/repo/debs/clang-llvm_3.1-1_iphoneos-arm.deb) (on jailbroken devices only) to compile C, C++ and Objective-C code on the device itself;
- And practically you can use any text editor and/or file manager application to write your code.

Comment: I have a jailbroken device, so claim toolchain will work. Thanks :).

Comment: @user2132312 That's nice to hear! You'll need to upload the appropriate development sysroot to your device as well (`iPhoneOSXX.Y.sdk`).

Answer (score 2):

The closet thing I know is [textastic-code-editor](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textastic-code-editor/id383577124?mt=8), however exist now a large list of apps, like for example [Code-Editors-For-the-iPad](http://blog.smartbear.com/software-quality/bid/195054/15-Code-Editors-For-the-iPad-For-Free-or-Very-Cheap)